# Bootstrap Table: data-href doesn't work after re-sorting

Tags: bootstrap-table

I’m using Bootstrap Table http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

All rows in the table are linked with data-href=.
All links work correctly after the table is loaded, but when I re-sort the table (i.e. click on "URL" column header), the links no longer work.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Here is a test code:

```
<table class="table" id="lst_art_adm"
                        data-toggle="table"
                        data-striped="true"
                        data-search="true"
                        data-sort-name="site"
                        data-sort-order="asc"
                        data-mobile-responsive="true"
                        mobileResponsive="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
                <th data-field="site" data-sortable="true">Site</th>
                <th data-field="url" data-sortable="true">URL</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="tr-id-1" class="mrow" data-href="https://google.com">
        <td id="td-id-1" data-sortable="true">Google</td>
        <td>google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="mrow" data-href="https://yahoo.com">
        <td id="td-id-2" data-sortable="true">Yahoo</td>
        <td>yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(function(){
     $(".mrow").on("click", function (e) {
          window.location = $(this).data("href");
     });
});
```

And the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/astoun/z863vhhb/20/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself :)
The table must be included in a div element, i.e. class="mytable".
Then the jquery should be changed like this:

```
$(function(){
     $(".mytable").on("click", ".table tbody tr", function() 
          window.location = $(this).data("href");
     });
});
```

Then the function will found the row after re-sorting.